# Seeing QGIS Python Commands

Tags: python, qgis

When learning MapBasic I found the most useful way to learn how to do certain tasks was to do them using the GUI and then watch the MapBasic window in MapInfo to see how they were achieved in code. It was also very useful for repeating repetitive tasks.

I was wondering if QGIS had something similar for python?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most of the commands in QGIS are hard-coded rather than scripted, so you can't get the output you want. That's not to say it wouldn't be possible for the developers to add such a feature because pretty much the entire API has Python bindings, but it wouldn't be trivial.

Plugins (at least Python ones which are encouraged over C++ ones) could possibly be scripted, but it depends how the plugin developer has coded it, and what sort of features are exposed.

I agree it would be a useful feature, but I suspect it'd require funded development.

Comment: This is something that I had a think about having a go at a while ago, however it wouldn't be easy task to undertake and would have to be funded.  QGIS was never really designed with this kind of output in mind.  Like MerseyViking said, it would be possible but IMO it would be bloody hard.

Comment: If anyone knows other applications that can do this kind of thing that are also open source, we might be able to have a look at the code a see what kind of stuff is involved.

Comment: It could possibly be tied into Qt's undo/redo framework, but currently only vector editing functions seem to use it. The print composer also has a command history, but I'm not sure if that's related in any way to the undo/redo system.