# Show MapBasic Window equivalent in QGIS, e.g. Python Window

Tags: qgis, data, sql, mapinfo, mapbasic

Is there a Show/Hide MapBasic Window (or equivalent) in QGIS such as in MapInfo?

I would like to learn SQL expressions parsing, or a Python Window viewer?

Comment: QGIS has a Python window where you can run Python code that can manipulate your maps. Or you can try running SQL queries in the QGIS attribute table.

Comment: How can I view such Python window?

Comment: I think this question has been answered by everyone. Also might interest you to read this post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14691/seeing-qgis-python-commands?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a simmilar thing as the MapInfo's "show/hide MapBasic" window in QGIS.
As [@MapinfoNewbie](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/118236/mapinfonewbie) sugests, it has been already discussed in this post:
[enter link description here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14691/seeing-qgis-python-commands?rq=1)

Python window, as far as I have experienced it, is meant for writing commands, edit them, etc... But one can not see the code being written automatically when operating with QGIS. For example, when I click "select" or "save project as..." I don't see the code being written in the python window, which is what I was looking for, and what one can see in the MapInfo "Show/hide MapBasic" window.

Answer (score 3):

You can view a python window. I would suggest referencing this page [QGIS Python console](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/python_console.html)

> The QGIS Python Console is an interactive shell for the python command executions. It also has a python file editor that allows you to edit and save your python scripts. Both console and editor are based on PyQScintilla2 package. To open the console go to Plugins ‣ Python Console

[image]

Also, you can refer to [Expressions, Filtering and Calculating Values¶](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/expressions.html#id1)

> QGIS has some support for parsing of SQL-like expressions. Only a small subset of SQL syntax is supported. The expressions can be evaluated either as boolean predicates (returning True or False) or as functions (returning a scalar value).